# надо and the instrumental case (knife cutting bread; a tool)

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I know about the use of dative case, or nominative case, as illustrated here: [How does "следует" behave towards "должен", "надо" and "нужно"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/6954/how-does-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-behave-towards-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-and-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be) when talking about things 'one must/should/etc. do', and that is why I am confused about why this sentence;

Хлеб н**а**до р**е**зать **о**стрым нож**о**м.

shouldn't actually be;

Хл**е**бу н**а**до р**е**зать **о**стрым нож**о**м.

---

Doesn't the bread **need** a sharp knife, like I need to drink water,

Мне н**а**до пить в**о**ду.

Comment: What you're actually trying to say by "the bread needs a sharp knife" can be expressed in Russian "Для хлеба нужен острый нож." Maybe this would help you understand the meaning of the 1st phrase: "Вам (и вообще, всем) хлеб надо (нужно) резать острым ножом."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Хлеб надо резать острым ножом.

**Хлеб** in this sentence is an object of the verb резать and is in the accusative case.

**Надо** *can* take a dative object (**To whom** is it needed?) but in this sentence it is omitted meaning "everyone / anyone" should cut bread with a sharp knife.

Comment: same about the second sentence with water, perhaps u add it into the answer too

Comment: @Arioch, I think you've just said it. :)

Comment: Both your answer and @Avtokod illustrate a difficulty - words being left out or implied. To approach this sentence (and others) possibly I should have recognized verbs need a direct object, which is always in accusative case, and from there look into words being left out?

Comment: @ Nate. You can  practice on these examples:  Надо мыть руки перед едой//Инструменты надо держать в специальном месте// Книгу надо читать внимательно// Воду в аквариуме надо менять каждые шесть месяцев // Суп надо варить на медленном огне// Собаку надо  выгуливать в наморднике//Дорогу надо переходить на зеленый свет светофора//

Comment: If we see ' надо+ the verb', then we look for the word in the dative case. Suppose this word is xxx. This means 'xxx must do'. If we do not find words in the dative, then this is  'we must do/ all must do' (everyone must cook the soup over low heat)